# How to redirect www.subdomain to subdomain with ssl Apache

Tags: ubuntu, ssl, redirect, apache2, wildcard

I want to redirect `http://www.subdomain.domain.com/` to `https://subdomain.domain.com`

First I'm going to explain you what I have, then what I have done, and whats happening.

This is what I have:

I have a webapp that is running on tomcat and I use Apache2 to do a proxy to the app.

I have a domain, let's call it `mydomain.com` and the main url for the webapp is `suba.mydomain.com` (`mydomain.com` and `www.mydomain.com` are been use for another thing). I also have a SSL wildcard for `*.mydomain.com`.

but I want this to happen:

- `http://www.suba.mydomain.com` redirects to `https://suba.mydomain.com`

This is what I have tried:

I have tried to do a redirect 301 from `http://www.suba.mydomain.com` to `https://suba.mydomain.com` and do a rewrite too(no simultaneous).

**Results**

When I type `www.suba.mydomain.com` I'm successfully been redirected to  `https://suba.mydomain.com` but when I try to do it again in the same web browser it display an error like this:

[image: Browser Error]

And it's because the web browser tries to add the `https://` and try to load the `*.mydomain.com` SSL wildcard that it's not going to be valid.

So in Google Chrome if I go to `chrome://net-internals/#hsts` and delete the `suba.mydomain.com` and the `www.suba.mydomain.com` and try again to type `www.suba.mydomain.com` I'm successfully been redirected to `https://suba.mydomain.com` again, but if I again try to do it, it won't work.

What can I do? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what you've described, it appears your site `suba.mydomain.com` is sending an [HTTP Strict-Transport-Security](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Strict-Transport-Security) response header with the `includeSubDomains` directive. This causes your browser to perform an internal redirect to the `https://` version of the site when you subsequently access `http://www.suba.mydomain.com` and your Apache rewrite rule does not kick in until a connection is made to the server (which requires the SSL handshake to be completed).

If you are indeed sending an HSTS header with `includeSubDomains`, see if removing it helps.

Here's what I suspect is happening:

1. You visit `http://www.suba.mydomain.com`, your rewrite rule in
   Apache redirects you to `https://suba.mydomain.com`.
2. `https://suba.mydomain.com` is sending an HSTS header, most likely
   with `includeSubDomains`, indicating all future requests made to [*.]suba.mydomain.com via insecure
   `http://` can be upgraded by the browser to `https://`.
3. When you visit `http://www.suba.mydomain.com` again, the browser will redirect you to `https://www.suba.mydomain.com` because of the cached HSTS setting.
4. You see the error because `https://www.suba.mydomain.com` does not match your certificate that is valid for `*.mydomain.com`. Your Apache rewrite rules will not run until a connection is made and that means accepting the certificate warning.
5. Deleting the HSTS entry from Chrome's cache as you've done will wipe the slate clean and you can access `http://www.suba.mydomain.com` once without warnings before running into the same issue.

Comment: It was that! Thanks!, I'm still using HTTP Strict-Transport-Security but without the `includeSubDomains`